# failing to free malloc

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

i created an array of pointers, each pointer point to a struct:

```
curr = (line_packet*)malloc(sizeof(line_packet)); //line packet is the struct
array = (line_packet*)malloc(sizeof(line_packet*) * counter_lines); //counter_lines the number of curr structs i created.
```

and each time i place a curr in array i use this line:

```
array[i] = *curr;
```

then at the end of the code i put this:

```
for (i = 0; i < counter_lines; i++)
{
    free(&array[i]);
}
free(array);
```

but it seems like the program fail to release the memory.
what should i do?
THANKS!

Comment: You probably want to change `*curr` to `curr` and `&array[i]` to `array[i]`.

Comment: Is that `&` a typo? If not it is the source of the problem.

Comment: `free(&array[i]);` is a guaranteed recipe for disaster. And the ill-advised casts on your allocations don't make much sense either. If you're allocating a `counter_lines` sequence of pointer-to line_packet, why cast the result to pointer-to line_packet. If anything it would be pointer-to-pointer-to line_packet. That alone tells me the mysterious type of `array` (not shown) is likely wrong, and that has a pretty overpowering code aroma. If `line_packet` is fixed (no flexible member) there is little sense in using multiple levels of indirection in this to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors.

For starters in this statement

```
array = (line_packet*)malloc(sizeof(line_packet*) * counter_lines);
```

you allocated an array of pointers of the type `line_packet*` and interpreted the returned pointer as a pointer of the type `line_packet *` instead of `line_packet **`.

You need to write at least like

```
array = (line_packet**)malloc(sizeof(line_packet*) * counter_lines);
```

provided that the pointer `array` has the type `line_packet **`.

So you may not write

```
array[i] = *curr;
```

because the expression `*curr` is not a pointer.

As a result this statement

```
free(&array[i]);
```

in the for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < counter_lines; i++)
{
    free(&array[i]);
}
free(array);
```

does not make a sense.

You need to write at least like

```
array[i] = malloc( sizeof( line_packet ) );

*array[i] = *curr;
```

In this case this loop

```
for (i = 0; i < counter_lines; i++)
{
    free(array[i]);
}
free(array);
```

will be correct provided that each element of the array either points to a dynamically allocated memory or a null pointer.

Or instead of the array of pointers you could allocate an array of objects of the type `line_packet`.

```
array = malloc(sizeof(line_packet) * counter_lines);
```

In this case this statement

```
array[i] = *curr;
```

will be correct.

However the loop

```
for (i = 0; i < counter_lines; i++)
{
    free(&array[i]);
}
```

shall be removed.